# Is it possible to upload a file to s3 via a lambda function using pre signed url?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

I have a scenario where I want to upload a file to s3 via a lambda function using pre-signed url.

Here One thing is important that What I want is to authorize lambda function using pre-signed url so that it can upload file to s3 and return an output to the user.

Here it looks like:

```
user asks to upload a file ---> a presigned url gets created --> (which will trigger lambda function to upload file to s3) --> lambda function return some output to the user.
```

Note: I already have successfully created a presigned url to directly upload to s3, which is working fine. but I want it to go through lambda function and return some response.

I need something like this but tot upload an image:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/transforming-objects.html

But not sure if it will work for uploading the image.

Can anyone please tell, how it can be done?

**EDIT**

I believe I need to invoke the lambda function from backend to get the presigned url.

But currently getting error

```
An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when calling the Invoke operation: 
User: arn:aws:iam::<user-id>:user 
is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: 
arn:aws:lambda:eu-east-1:<user-id>:function:function 
because no identity-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action
```

I also have `AWSLambdaRole` permission to the user.

This code I am using to invoke lambda funtion:

```
response = client.invoke(
   FunctionName=FunctionName,
   InvocationType='RequestResponse',
   LogType='None',
   Payload=json.dumps(payload)
)
```

Comment: Why would you use pre-sign url for that? Lambda can access S3 directly, without the url.

Comment: @Marcin What I basically want is that I want to send a request to lamda using browser and lambda then upload the image to s3 and after upload lambda should send a response back to the browser like shown in the link i've posted about "transforming object" in the image. But I am unable to actually create this. Can you tell me how can I achieve this flow?

Comment: From where is the image file coming? If it is coming from the user's computer, then they will need to upload via their browser. The Lambda function does not have access to files on their computer.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein I've updated the question, i want to invoke the lambda function from backend to get the presigned url, Can you help me with it.

Comment: I am still confused. The normal method would be to have the front-end should call API Gateway to request a pre-signed URL, and API Gateway will trigger a Lambda function to generate the pre-signed URL, returning it to the front-end. The front-end will then use the pre-signed URL to directly upload the file to S3. Does that map to what you are wanting to do?

Comment: Yes i know, but i must to do this one using the invoke function, Is it possible to invoke function from backend, I've posted the code in my question under EDIT you can see.

Can you please tell if its possible?

Answer (score 1):

A presigned URL is a URL that you can provide to your users to grant temporary access to a specific S3 object, it have limited lifetime, so this does not make so much sense to use it with Lambda, that can access the s3 bucket directly.

But if you have a specific need to upload using a presigned url in a Lambda, you can do this in the following way:

```
import boto3
    url = boto3.client('s3').generate_presigned_url(
    ClientMethod='put_object', 
    Params={'Bucket': 'BUCKET_NAME', 'Key': 'OBJECT_KEY'},
    ExpiresIn=3600)
```

You can find other examples in other programming languages here: [Uploading objects using presigned URLs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/PresignedUrlUploadObject.html)

Comment: Can I send the request to lambda via browser which then upload to s3 and send back some response?

Comment: To do this you will need to use API gateway https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/api-gateway-upload-image-s3/

Comment: Do you think that this helped you @code0x00 ?

Comment: I've updated the question, i want to invoke the lambda function from backend to get the presigned url, Can you help me with it.

Comment: Try to add the Lambda policy Summary in your question